# How to define a multi-dimensional neural network with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have implemented a simple neural network with keras that takes an input of 50 values and returns a classification of '0' or '1'. I believe the model is expecting an input shape of (50, 1). I'd like to add another 50 data values for each input, but I'd like them to be associated with the original 50 respective inputs. So instead of making the input of shape (100, 1), I guess I'd like to make it of shape (50, 2). I would like the neural network to know from the start that each input feature has two values associated with it, instead of it thinking there are 100 separate input features. Here's what I have so far:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Can anyone show me the way the alter this structure to accept my new input shape?

Comment: Can you please clarify, you have one example with 50 features (1, 50) or 50 examples with 1 feature (50, 1)

Comment: I have one example with 50 features.  I never explicitly defined the input shape.  I believe the NN is looking for a shape of (50,1) because that's what I have to reshape my input vector to in order for it to work.  I'm looking to add an additional parameter to each of my input features but instead of a 100 element vector, I'm wondering if I need a (50, 2) or (2, 50) input shape.  I'd like each of the new additional features to be associated with particular features from the original 50.

Comment: So in Keras inputs are (batch size, input size, feature size). You would want (1, 50) for 50 features and if you want a 100 dimensional vector you would reshape to (1, 100). Right now you are actually just inputting 50 inputs of 1 feature.

Comment: Have you tried a multi-input NN?